# Contentful - create and publish in single request?

Tags: curl, contentful

Does anyone know if it's possible to create *and* publish an entry in a single request in Contentful's Content Management API?

It seems instead you have to make a second call to the `/published` endpoint to publish the newly-created entry.

Create request:

```
curl --include \
     --request PUT \
     --header 'Authorization: Bearer <cma_token>' \
     --header 'X-Contentful-Content-Type: something' \
     --data-binary <request body as JSON>
     https://api.contentful.com/spaces/<space_id>/environments/<env_id>/entries/<entry_id>
```

Publish request:

```
curl --include \
     --request PUT \
     --header 'Authorization: Bearer <cma_token>' \
     --header 'X-Contentful-Version: <published version>' \
     https://api.contentful.com/spaces/<space_id>/environments/<env_id>/entries/<entry_id>/published
```

I've tried adding that `X-Contentful-Version` header into the creation request, but it seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

That's right. [The docs describe two endpoints](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/entries/entry-publishing/publish-an-entry/console/curl) for the two actions (entry creation and publishing). Every created entry will be created unpublished and has to be published with another API call.

Comment: Thank you, appreciated. I wouldn't agree the docs make this explicit; it merely says there are dedicated endpoints for both processes without saying explicitly that you can't publish when you create - particularly since, with the import API, you indeed *can* do that. But then the docs have various problems!

Comment: Right. :) I'll get that fixed. The import tooling uses the CMA and does make two calls, too. ;)

Comment: Oh - that makes sense, then. Appreciate the help as always, Stefan.

Comment: Happy to help. :) I'll add a side sentence tmrw then.

Comment: Cool. Might also be good to make explicit that with the [docs](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/entries/entry-publishing/unpublish-an-entry/console/curl) for unpublishing, the idea is to lower the published version number. Took me a while to realise that the only difference between the publish and *un*publish code samples is the different (lower) version number for unpublish :)